# How to use checkboxes in react native?

Tags: react-native, jsx

I got a list of topics which user can select and after that I will make api call based on their chosen topics, I got it all working but I need to change the texts to checkboxes

**Here is my state:**

```
     this.state = {
      loading: false,
      dataSource: [],
      error: null,
      topic: '',
  }
```

**Here is my api call:**

```
   getUsers = () => {
    fetch('https://someapi.com/?topic=' + this.state.topic, {method: 'GET'}).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        error: responseJson.error || null,
        dataSource: responseJson.data.users,
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.setState({error, loading: false});
    });
  }
```

**Here my topic in render method that are working perfectly but I need to change texts to checkboxes:**

```
    <View>
     <Text onPress={(text) => this.setTopic('topic-slug1')}>Some Topic</Text>
     <Text onPress={(text) => this.setTopic('topic-slug2')}>Some Topic</Text> 
     <Text onPress={(text) => this.setTopic('topic-slug3')}>Some Topic</Text>           
    </View>
```

**And here is `setTopic()` function:**

```
   setTopic(searchedTopic) {
    this.setState({topic: searchedTopic});
  }
```

I just need to use **Checkboxes** insted of `<Text>` to use both on **Android** and **IOS**

Comment: https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-check-box#readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, you have to add condition based on checkbox checked is true or false

Here is a demo with plugin : https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-check-box#readme

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        topic: null,
        checkTopic1: false,
        checkTopic2: false,
        checkTopic3: false,
    }
}

setTopic = (slug) => {
    if(slug == "topic-slug1"){
        this.setState({
            checkTopic1:!this.state.checkTopic1
        })
    }else if(slug == "topic-slug2"){
        this.setState({
            checkTopic2:!this.state.checkTopic2
        })
    }else if(slug == "topic-slug3"){
        this.setState({
            checkTopic3:!this.state.checkTopic3
        })
    }
    this.setState({
        topic: slug
    })
    this.getUsers();
}

getUsers = () => {
    fetch('https://someapi.com/?topic=' + this.state.topic, {method: 'GET'}).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        error: responseJson.error || null,
        dataSource: responseJson.data.users,
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.setState({error, loading: false});
    });
}


<View>
    <CheckBox
        style={{flex: 1, padding: 10}}
        onClick={()=> this.setTopic('topic-slug1')}
        isChecked={this.state.checkTopic1}
        leftText={"Some Topic"}
    />
    <CheckBox
        style={{flex: 1, padding: 10}}
        onClick={()=> this.setTopic('topic-slug2')}
        isChecked={this.state.checkTopic2}
        leftText={"Some Topic"}
    />
    <CheckBox
        style={{flex: 1, padding: 10}}
        onClick={()=> this.setTopic('topic-slug3')}
        isChecked={this.state.checkTopic3}
        leftText={"Some Topic"}
    />
</View>
```